# Adding Cookies working with Firefox webdriver but not in PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-scraping, phantomjs

I have a pickle with cookies that I create through the following command

```
def doLogin(driver):
    #do login stuff
    pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open("cookies.pkl", "wb"))
```

I have the sample code to get the cookies

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
self.doLogin(driver)
driver.delete_all_cookies()
for cookie in pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb")):
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

I can see that it creates the cookie well because if I `print` it it's fine the add_cookie() is doing shady things

This gives the following exception

> WebDriverException: Message: {"errorMessage":"Unable to set
>   Cookie","request":{"headers":{"Accept":"application/json","Accept-Encoding":"identity","Connection":"close","Content-Length":"219","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8","Host":"127.0.0.1:50738","User-Agent":"Python-urllib/2.7"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"sessionId\":
>   \"391db430-154a-11e6-8a0a-ef59204729f5\", \"cookie\": {\"domain\":
>   \"secretWebsite\", \"name\": \"JSESSIONID\", \"value\":
>   \"8332B6099FA3BBBC82893D4C7E6E918B\", \"path\": \"Also a secret\",
>   \"httponly\": false, \"secure\":
>   true}}","url":"/cookie","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"cookie","directory":"/","path":"/cookie","relative":"/cookie","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/cookie","queryKey":{},"chunks":["cookie"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/391db430-154a-11e6-8a0a-ef59204729f5/cookie"}}
>   Screenshot: available via screen

To work, all I need is to change webdriver to Firefox

Is this a known PhantomJS issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that some key/values are not supported by the PhantomJS driver.
To overcome this issue, I would inject the most important ones with `execute_script`:

```py
def save_cookies(driver, file_path):
    LINE = "document.cookie = '{name}={value}; path={path}; domain={domain}; expires={expires}';\n"
    with open(file_path, 'w') as file :
        for cookie in driver.get_cookies() :
            file.write(LINE.format(**cookie))

def load_cookies(driver, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        driver.execute_script(file.read())


from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()

# load the domain
driver.get("https://stackoverflow.com/users/login")

# save the cookies to a file
save_cookies(driver, r"cookies.js")

# delete all the cookies
driver.delete_all_cookies()

# load the cookies from the file
load_cookies(driver, r"cookies.js")
```

Comment: I was able to narrow down the problem to this issue https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13115
Your code works beautifully, I changed the script on saving a little bit to fit to my cookies, for example 'JSESSIONID' didnt have an 'expires' field
You are the MAN! I love you!